# How does curl would return error code 1?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I want to use google oauth to login in my website.

The code is working find in my localhost.

Howevery, it always gets null when connects to https.

Finally, I wrote a simple code to check the problem.

Here is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com.tw");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);//for ssl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);//for ssl
curl_exec($ch);
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    //I use the library downloaded form http://code.blitzaffe.com/pages/phpclasses/category/52/fileid/7
    //It does not support curl_strerror;
    //Therefore, I cannot show the message got from curl_strerror;

    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n  <br/>";
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Screen shown :

```
cURL error (1):
```

Also, I had tried to login in the server adn run

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com.tw:443
```

It do connect!!

How could curl return error code 1?

And how can I fix it?

Comment: It's kind of an important point that you use a curl_* function emulation script. You can look up what code `1` refers to then right in said script. Did you really check for OpenSSL support in your PHP install like the instructions said?

Comment: I can find ssl,  sslv3, and sslv2 in Registered Stream Socket Transports via phpinfo(); I think this means my server support it?